# What is the best way to implement kind of getNext on results using REST (restlet)

Tags: java, http, rest, restlet, put

I'm writing a web service which returns results. This results are some data that is being created on the server all the time. So when the client asks for a resource i want to give him also a url for the next query he can preform to get the new data created on the server.
For example, client can start with the following url:

```
http://ip:port/server/{id}/resource
```

and next time he should use something like:

```
http://ip:port/server/{id}/resource/1234
```

where 1234 is some pointer to the server to know which result the client has already recieved.
So the question is, where do i return the url to the next set of results? should it be in the header or in the body?
I read some reference about usage of url parameters vs. query, and if i understood for chaching i better use uri rather then query.
Last thing, i need to pass info the body for the request and therefore the web service expects PUT and not GET.
Restlet example will be mostly appreciated.

One last thing, i must have {id} in the url, but there is no such uri as

```
 http://ip:port/server
```

so what would be the right way for users to know there id? (the results are returned per user's id). the id ia allocated by completly different resource.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an alternate approach using conditional GETs.  In this approach, the server responds to GET requests with an ETag and/or Last-Modified response header to indicate when the resource was last modified.  This would be "1234" in your example above.  The client then supplies that value on a subsequent GET to the same URI as earlier, providing it in an If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since header.

I have a similar service implemented using Restlet that is continuously receiving updates, and likewise, clients want to periodically fetch information newer than what they received previously.  I use ETags.

In my ServerResource-derived class, I have code like this:

```
import org.restlet.data.Tag;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.representation.Variant;

public class FooCollectionServerResource extends ServerResource implements FooCollectionResource {

    private Tag mResponseTag;

    @Override public FooCollection getFooCollection() {
        List<Tag> tags = getRequest().getConditions().getNoneMatch();
        Tag eTag = null;
        if (!tags.isEmpty())
            eTag = tags.get(0);

        // might be an empty collection, if there are no new/modified Foos since eTag
        FooCollection result = getFoosSince(eTag); 

        mResponseTag = new Tag("1234"); // hardcoded here, but you get the idea
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public Representation toRepresentation(final Object source, final Variant target) {
        Representation result = super.toRepresentation(source, target);
        result.setTag(mResponseTag);
        return result;
    }
}
```

One trick here is that you can't set the ETag header value directly in the getFoo() method; you have to tuck it away in a field and use it in the toRepresentation() override.  This is because of the timing of when the response Representation is created in Restlet.